# Get youtube trends v3 country wise in Json?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to get youtube trends of **most popular** or **most viewed** by country wise in Json.

Previously using youtube feeds v2. It seems deprecated,
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/IN/most_popular?v=2

Can I get youtube api v3 or any other result like the trends dashboard,
https://www.youtube.com/trendsdashboard

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As per YouTube guidelines, [YouTube Feeds v2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds), is now deprecated. You should work with [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

For the most popular video:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&maxResults=25&key=API_KEY

1. **part**:

   - The part names that you can include in the parameter value are:

     - `id, snippet, contentDetails, fileDetails, liveStreamingDetails, localizations, player, processingDetails, recordingDetails, statistics, status, suggestions, and topicDetails`
2. **chart**:

   - The chart parameter identifies the chart that you want to retrieve (*string*)

     - Example `mostPopular`
3. **regionCode**:

   - The parameter value is an *ISO 3166-1 alpha-2* country code (*string*)
4. **key**:

   - [Google Project API key](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+google+api+key+for+youtube&oq=how+to+get+google+api+key+for+youtube)
5. **maxResults** : Default value 5 ,

[Read More](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Comment: @AshishChaturvedi Thanks for the answer. But this URL gives only four results. I mean four videos. Is there way to get at least 10 vidoes?

Comment: @Sasa1234 by default is provide 5 results, For more you should use &maxResults=25

Comment: please can i get older trending videos? for example adding a parameter for date like &date=2-2-16

Answer (score 3):

```
var maxVideos = 5;
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",{
      part: 'snippet',
      chart: 'mostPopular',
      kind: 'youtube#videoListResponse',
      maxResults: maxVideos,
      regionCode: 'IN',
      key: 'Your_KEY_Here'},
      function(data){
        var output;
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
          console.log(item);
          videTitle = item.snippet.title;
                description = item.snippet.description;
                thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
                channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;
                videoDate = item.snippet.publishedAt;
                Catagoryid = item.snippet.categoryId;
                cID = item.snippet.channelId;
          output = '<div class="maindiv"><div>' +
                        '<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="fancyboxIframe" href="watch.php?v=' + vidId + '" target="_blank" ><img src="' + thumb + '" class="img-responsive thumbnail" ></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="input-group col-md-6">' +
                            '<h3 class="Vtitle"><a data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="fancyboxIframe" href="watch.php?v=' + vidId + '" target="_blank">' + videTitle + '</a></h3>'+
                        '</div><div  id="cTitle"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/'+cID+'" target="_blank">'+channelTitle+'</a></div></div>' +
                    '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
          $('#trending').append(output);
        })

      }
    );
});
```

Save file as `.js`

And in `HTML` file make `div` or `ul` by `id="trending"`

like:

```
<div id="catagoryname"><h1>Trending</h1></div>
      <ul id="trending"></ul>
```

The check your out put.

- Note
  Don't forget to Replace your `API KEY`