# Is it possible for me to get the current trending topics from Youtube?

Tags: java, json, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

Currently, I'm working on getting the latest trend on Youtube. Is there a way to get the JSON Object so that I can use it in my java code.

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475309/get-youtube-trends-v3-country-wise-in-json)

Comment: can you help me out with that I will be thankful for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From V3 you can use the following  (from API Reference)

> HTTP request
>
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos

[API Reference for Videos List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

For what you intend the chart parameter of the query string is what you need, and it accepts mostPopular

The response is JSON as the following taken from their API example.

> {
>     "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
>     "etag": etag,
>     "nextPageToken": string,
>     "prevPageToken": string,
>     "pageInfo": {
>       "totalResults": integer,
>       "resultsPerPage": integer
>     },
>     "items": [
>       video Resource
>     ]
>   }